# from query to path in subdirectory HTACCESS

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've an https domain with WordPress installed in the root directory.
In the subdirectory "/test/" i made a web application that works using GET; the path is something like that:

> https://www.example.com/test/file.php?url=urlname&etc=etc

I need to transform it in:

> https://www.example.com/test/urlname/?etc=etc

I also need a redirect from the first type url to the second one.

It's the first time that i have to edit an htaccess file, and after searching on the web i tried this code

```
RewriteRule ^/?test/([^/]+)/$ test/file.php?url=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/test/file\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^url=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/?test/file\.php$ /test/%1/?%{QUERY_STRING}  [L,R=301]
```

but it obviously doesn't work.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /test/file\.php\?url=([^\s&]+)(?:&(\S*))?\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /test/%1?%2 [R=301,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^test/([^/]+)/?$ test/file.php?url=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```